# How to make the Mouse look smoother in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a simple mouse look Script for my first person game I have already made a very smooth and easy Movement script And when It comes to camera it is a problem I tried everything I know to make it smoother and easy WITH NOT MANY LINE OF CODES .

So as result it was good. you can look around
But not smooth there is a bit of lagging.

check this video I uploaded How it works for me [ Link Below ]

https://youtu.be/FH1WbPayf2I

As you can see in the beginning I was moving and its smooth then I look around and its horrible

You can check the code by yourself

Script `mouseLook`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class mouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    float mouseX;
    float mouseY;

    public float sensitivity = 100f;
    public Transform player;
    float rotation = 0f;
    
    public float minAngle = -90f;
    public float maxAngle = 90f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

        rotation -= mouseY;
        rotation = Mathf.Clamp(rotation, minAngle, maxAngle);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotation, 0, 0);

        player.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);

    }
}
```

So If you have any idea about how to make it more smoother or New script I will be thankful . And please make sure its not complicated I'm still a beginner its been 6 months since I started So if there is a new thing will added to the script hope to give a comment about what it does. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using `transform.localRotation`. You are probably trying to control the camera which is a child of the **Player** (if not, then `transform.rotation` would be enough). But in the same script, you are modifying the Player’s rotation, so all children’s rotation too. That’s why the overall result is kinda doubled.

So, the solution is to control just the **Player**, e.g. remove `transform.localRotation` assignment. **The camera will be rotated as a child of the Player.**

Also, it’s better to use LateUpdate, so you 100% will capture the actual position.

Comment: it is a child of the player And using LateUpdate will not help . still lagging

Comment: LateUpdate is just a small optimization. The main idea is not to control camera. Because when you rotate Player, camera rotates too because it’s a child of Player. So, just don’t rotate camera’s transform. Remove this transform.localRotation assignment

Comment: What you’ve got is not a lag. You do rotate Player. The Player rotates, then camera rotates too as a child of Player. Then you rotate the camera one more time with the code. That’s why the resulting rotation is wrong